# Applying \mathrm on \mu leads to strange symbol

Tags: math-mode

I would like to know how to fix this:
`\mathrm{\mu}` produces the strange looking symbol: [image]

I think this appeared recently in one of my larger `.tex` files.

The MWE however looks fine except it is still italique.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{\mu}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `upgreek` package.

Comment: `\mathrm{\mu}` is useless in any case.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, as it seems. I was just wondering because I thought it once displayed it correctly. But then I guess I just remember wrongly.

Comment: @Bernard thanks. I will consider this.

Comment: May we ask exactly what you need an upright mu for? If it is for units, then use `siunitx`

Comment: Yes it is for units, I actually use the `siunitx` package. I just wonder why this would happen.

Comment: @stephanmg By default, `\mathrm` is set to an 8-bit encoding that supports uppercase but not lowercase Greek. There are a few ways to change that.

Comment: @Davislor ah, great. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, if you want to give a constant in an equation the name μ, you can load `unicode-math` and use `\symup{mu}` for an upright Greek μ.  In legacy LaTeX, you can load `isomath` with the `OMLmathrm` option and `rmdefault=` to load an 8-bit `\mathrm` font that supports Greek.  (As of 2020, this only works with the `mathdesign` fonts.)  You can also use Greek fonts in the 8-bit LGR encoding with `mathastext`.  The `\mathrm{\mu}` command will also work if you load `fontspec` and `\setmainfont` or `\setmathrm` to a font that supports Greek.

Without any of these, `\mathrm{\mu}` fails because `\mathrm` is set by default to a legacy 7-bit encoding with no lowercase Greek letters.  TeX is giving you mojibake.

However, if you want the SI micro symbol, you want the package `siunitx`, or something like `\newcommand\micrometers{\textnormal{~{\textmicro}m}}`.